# How does flex and flex-box works with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm learning CSS and for most of my work I use bootstrap. While building a static webpage, I discovered this property called flex in bootstrap5 utilities.

I understand that the point of flex is to make items align easily.

What I don't understand is:

While creating a `div` if we use this code

*Code 1*

```html
<div class="mt-5">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <h5 class="h5 text-font">Credits.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

It aligns the content in center perfectly.

However, when I use the `d-flex` class in the outer div, it doesn't move from start.

*Code 2*

```html
<div class="d-flex mt-5">
  <div class="justify-content-center">
    <h5 class="h5 text-font">Credits.</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some questions in my mind related to Bootstrap5 flex are:

- So in this case why doesn't the heading move to the center when it's content are justified to center and parent div is a d-flex?
- How does moving elements inside a d-flex class in bootstrap5 works?
- What's the difference in working of d-flex in *code 1* and *code 2*?

Comment: *What is a flex-box, and how is it different from flex?* --> I really advise you reading the basic of CSS and flexbox before moving to bootstrap.

Comment: It's not like I just jumped to stackoverflow, I tried reading the docs it's not my fault that they haven't  explained it properly

Comment: judging from your question, you didn't read the correct docs. Search for better sources, there is a lot of great one in the net. (MDN, CSS-tricks, etc)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: _Flex_ and _Flexbox_ are synonyms. Both terms refer to the [**CSS Flexbox Layout Module**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I should add that **Bootstrap** is a framework and adopts a *Utility CSS* approach to styling. Once you become even a little bit proficient with **Flexbox** and **CSS Grid**, you likely won't need **Bootstrap** any more.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the first question, any answers on the last 3 ?

Comment: Very strange this Q got 3 upvotes. Multiple questions in a single post are off-topic. *"I tried reading the docs it's not my fault that they haven't explained it properly"* Understanding CSS flexbox parent/child comes before using Bootstrap.

Comment: With all due respect. Multiple "different" questions in a single post are off-topic, while all of my questions are related to single topic.

Comment: Where do I find how to use the [Run Snippet] feature? It doesn't appear in a search or their FAQ.